# Cannot upgrade to 17.04 - has gpg key changed?

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, updates, 17.04

I can't upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 17.04 due to this error when i run sudo do-release-upgrade:

authenticate 'zesty.tar.gz' against 'zesty.tar.gz.gpg' 
gpg exited 2
Debug information:

gpg: Signature made using RSA key ID C0B21F32
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found

i already refreshed my repos before running the command

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So i solve this by going to "Software and Updates Center" and restoring the defaults for the trusted software key providers